# How to search array item with given string

Tags: php

i have an array:

```
$mainArr = ["SRI", "AIS", "GOW","SRI#AIS","SRI#GOW", "SRI#GOW#AIS"];

$strArr = ["SRI"];
```

i want to search the main Array with the given string Array element so that if the string is matched it should get the corresponding key,value pair.

expected o/p would be:

```
Array[
    0->SRI
    3->SRI#AIS
    4->SRI#GOW
    5->SRI#AIS#GOW
]
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks,
Srinivas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mainArr = array("SRI", "AIS", "GOW","SRI#AIS","SRI#GOW", "SRI#GOW#AIS");

$strArr = array("SRI");
foreach ($mainArr as $key => $value)
{
    foreach ($strArr as $str)
    {
        if (strpos($value,$str) !== false) $rez[$key] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($rez);
```

output:

```
    array(4) { 
[0]=> string(3) "SRI" 
[3]=> string(7) "SRI#AIS" 
[4]=> string(7) "SRI#GOW" 
[5]=> string(11) "SRI#GOW#AIS" 
}
```

Comment: i dont think foreach will workout here, bcoz my original array has 4000 elements and string array contains 10 elements.is there any option like in_array ? or array_search ?

Comment: if u have so many elements u have to create another array where u'll store all matches. `in_array` and `array_search` can't be used straight since u don't want to find strings *exactly* the same as ur search pattern

Comment: i think using array filter with the logic u have mentioned with strpos will workout here, instead of using two foreach loops.

Comment: i liked your answer but not able to increase the votes since iam new member overh here. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: emm... i can't figure out how u can pass `$strArr` to the filter function

Comment: oh. yaa. didnt noticed. i cant send the $strArr to filter function. then two foreach loops will be the solution ???

Comment: yes. using the same way. its working. only concern is its a big array with 4000 elements.but functionality is workign fine. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_filter`:

```
function filter($element)
{
    return strpos($element, 'SRI') !== false;
}

$mainArr = array("SRI", "AIS", "GOW","SRI#AIS","SRI#GOW", "SRI#GOW#AIS");
$filteredArr = array_filter($mainArr, 'filter');
```

Comment: No problem :) Note that in the function you're testing with the strict inequality operator, as `strpos()` might return `false` or `0`, depending on whether the substring you're looking for is not present at all, or is merely at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I thing i ll help  u,,

```
$test=array();
        $mainArr = array("SRI", "AIS", "GOW","SRI#AIS","SRI#GOW", "SRI#GOW#AIS");
        $strArr = array("SRI");
        foreach ($mainArr as $key => $value)
        {
            $temp   = explode('#',$value);
            //$temp = $temp[0];
            if(in_array($temp[0],$strArr))
            $test[$key]=$value; 
        }
        echo "<pre><span style='color:black; font-size:19;'>";print_r($test);echo "</span></pre>";
```

Comment: @k102:2nd Forecho i thing it wont nessary for his coding

Comment: your solution has several limitations: what if i have element like this: `"SRI||AIS"` or what if like this: `"GOW#SRI"`. this is why i used two foreach